How can I view manual changes so far in an ongoing merge?
In Git, my merge is still ongoing (no commit yet). 98% of the changes that show up in git diff are related to what MERGE_HEAD (and parent history singe merge-base) brought. 1% is my work from HEAD and the rest is some manual tweaks and fixes I had to make as part of the merge itself. How to find those? It's kind of like looking for a needle in a haystack. All variants on git diff yield changes coming from MERGE_HEAD:
git diff HEAD

git diff $(git merge-base HEAD MERGE_HEAD)

I don't know what to do.

Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].

If you don't want to see the changes between your target branch and the merge base (git diff HEAD), nor the modifications between the other branch and the merge base (git diff MERGE_HEAD), but only the edits you've made so far during the conflict resolution, you could run
git diff AUTO_MERGE

Quoting the AUTO_MERGE documentation in the Description section of git diff:

A tree of interest is the one pointed to by the ref named AUTO_MERGE, which is written by the ort merge strategy upon hitting merge conflicts (see git-merge[1]). Comparing the working tree with AUTO_MERGE shows changes you’ve made so far to resolve textual conflicts


“merge basis”—merge base?

@Guildenstern You can refer to it in both ways. The book "Version control with Git" by Jon Loeliger, for example, often prefers merge basis to merge base. To quote an extract at page 140 about the Resolve merge strategy: "The resolve strategy operates on only two branches, locating the common ancestor as the merge basis and performing a direct three-way merge by applying the changes from the merge base to the tip of the other branch HEAD onto the current branch". Both expressions are fine. Merge base is just more common I guess.

Thanks, that’s fine. I’m more concerned that the term is never used in the Git documentation. But I’m just here to nitpick :·)

Yeah, your comment actually made look into it just to realize that marge basis is not used in Git documentation at all. No problem about "nitpicking" btw :) it was a valid comment to clarify something that could have been misunderstood.

@Guildenstern Please nitpick as much as needed. Terminology is important for good communication, efficient and precise - especially when English isn't one's mother tongue, as is my case. My two cents on the matter at hand is, the command is git merge-base ergo I use that.

@Charles I agree. I had updated my answer accordingly.

@dani-vta Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. I did encounter such things :
-<<<<<<< HEAD
-    m_pInputHandler->resetData();
and
-=======
->>>>>>> origin/from_branch
}
What to make of them ?

@Charles I'm glad I could help! I've just seen you've edited your original comment (the previous one was a bit hard to read), but that looks like the changes you've made so far on ClassA.cpp (your edits during the conflict resolution). From Git CLI, your additions are preceded with a + and highlighted in green, while your deletions are preceded with a - and highlighted in red.

Yes but specifically it seems that, according to that diff, I removed the special code highlighting the area of merge conflicts - and indeed there were a few. Is this because I resolved the merge conflict (using my mergetool) ?

If you've used a mergetool, it probably removed the three-way marker automatically (the symbols <<<<, ====, >>>>) once you've marked the conflict as resolved. That's why the appeared in red. If you were to resolve a conflict manually, you'd have to delete the three-way marker symbols on your own.

I think I've got it all explained then. Actually viewing the conflict markers removed is a pretty decent visual to show me that I went through conflict resolution at this code location and stuff. Thank you for everything !
